# usr/bin/ld -lpthtread not found

Tags: 14.04

I am trying to install TRIQS-1.0.0(git clone https://github.com/TRIQS/triqs.git src)  on Pentium(R) Dual Core 32-bit Ubuntu 14.04 system.
Using the following commands

```
 mkdir build && cd build
 cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/build../src
```

the system returns  `-lpthreads not found` even though all dependencies are installed.

Where can can I find pthreads in Ubuntu 14.04?
The relevant part of the output log is shown below.:

```
Determining if the function pthread_create exists in the pthreads failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/enukpere/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
Run Build Command:/usr/bin/make "cmTryCompileExec2501535256/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2501535256.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2501535256.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/enukpere/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/enukpere/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2501535256.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create   -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2501535256.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o   -c /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.c
Linking C executable cmTryCompileExec2501535256
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2501535256.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create    CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2501535256.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o cmTryCompileExec2501535256 -rdynamic -lpthreads 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthreads
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [cmTryCompileExec2501535256] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/enukpere/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make: *** [cmTryCompileExec2501535256/fast] Error
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the following dependencies (`libboost` version is 1.54 in 14.04):

```
sudo apt-get install cmake git g++ libgfortran3 gfortran openmpi-bin openmpi-common \
     openmpi-checkpoint libopenmpi-dev libblas-dev liblapack-dev libfftw3-dev libgmp-dev \
     hdf5-tools libhdf5-serial-dev python-h5py libboost1.54-all-dev python-dev \
     python-numpy python-scipy python-virtualenv python-matplotlib doxygen\
     python-tornado python-zmq python-mpi4py cython
```